# Beginner NodeJS Questions. "Create a download for a user" and avoid multiple same server calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, backend

I recently started to get into web programming and I started to learn NodeJS. It's a bit overwhelming at the moment, so I thought I could ask here for an 
enlightenment.

Basically my main goal is to create a page, where a user can input specific data and click a button. Based on the data the user will receive a download or an alert which says something like "Cant download the file".

My ajax call and stuff working fine. I have a function which tries to create a file and return a path of the file (or an object, which contains the error message). But I don't want the the user to "restart" the function with a button.

Example: User fills the data and presses the button. An ajax calls happen and a function gets started. And when the user represses the button while the function is still running, the complete process will just get restarted. I want my program to be like that (has to be on server side!)

-> CHECK if the process is running? 
If yes -> Alert a message "Cant start the process". 
If no -> Start the process and return a download or an error message.

Code:

HTML Button: (Note; `dataA`, `dataB`, `dataC` are just text fields)

```
 <input type="button" onclick="callServerSideScript('dataA','dataB','dataC')" value="Get Build" class="button">
```

Client side JavaScript :

```
function callServerSideScript(dataA,dataB,dataC){
    a = document.getElementById(dataA).value;
    b = document.getElementById(dataB).value;
    c = document.getElementById(dataC).value;
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    httpRequest.open('POST', '/buildRequest')
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpRequest.send("firstData="+a+"&secondData="+b+"&thirdData="+c);
   }
```

NodeJS/ExpressJS - server side JS (Note - `dbFunctions` is a function which does all the backend stuff and trying to create the output file. If success it returns a "path-string"; if failed it returns an Object.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var dbFunc = require("./dbFunctions.js");
    var util = require('util');
    var app = express();
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var port = 8888;
    //allow to use body-parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    //allow to use static files
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    //listen to smth
    app.post('/buildRequest', function (req, res) {
        var main=dbFunc.main(req.body.firstData,req.body.secondData,req.body.thirdData,function(data) {
                var result = data;
                if(util.isString(result)){
//in this case the user would just reicive the download                     
console.log("result is string");
                    var filePath = result;
                    res.download(filePath);
                }else{
                    //in this case the user should receive an alert containing a stringify of the object
console.log("result is not an string");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                }    
        });

    });
    //start server

    app.listen(port);
    console.log("Server running on port" + port);
```

I have read a bit about `res.download()` but somehow the download won't appear.

Also no error message appears.

Simple `alert();` also doesn't work (like in client side JavaScript).

Hopefully my code is understandable and you understand my problem.

Comment: So, this seems to be a question more about the confusion between how the client and the server communicate. The server doesn't show any UI, so you're not going to be able to call `alert()`. All the server does is listen for requests (`req`) and respond (`res`) to them. Thus, you'll want to change the `else` there to respond as well. I expect there's a `res.json()` or something similar which you can use to send back data.

Comment: Well first the `alert()` won't work on the server side since it's not tied into the javascript on the physical page loaded. Secondly in your `app.post()` I believe you need to call your function as it is never run. So at the end of it type `main()` or rework it to just run automatically.

Comment: My functions get called  with this line "var main=dbFunc.main". dbFunc get created at the start with "dbFunc = require(./dbFunctions.js")"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use async methods so you can solve the problem using a simple locking approach.

Also, have a look at the following link and scroll down to see the results as a Gif image, I think that's what you're looking for.

[Synchronization of concurrent HTTP requests in NodeJS](https://60devs.com/synchronization-of-concurrent-http-requests-in-node.html)